# Spring MVC : import collides with another import statement

Tags: java, spring-mvc, import

I have the following:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import au.edu.unimelb.atcom.common.model.Controller;
```

Eclipse gives me the error:

> The import au.edu.unimelb.atcom.common.model.Controller collides with another import statement

The only instance I'm using either is in the controller annotation, which I have changed to:

```java
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
```

I'm still getting the conflict. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I don't understand, with only a single import statement, you still get an import statement collision?

Comment: Good point, I guess you should only import the one you're using most to reduce the code length, since `@Controller` will only occur once but my `Controller` may be used in many places.

Answer (score 2):

Using the full name to declare my own class works and requires no explicit import:

```
private au.edu.unimelb.atcom.common.model.Controller test;
```

And the annotation remains as `@Controller`.

Comment: +1. i was just to write the same thing, why you OP are so impatient? =)

Comment: sorry, that was probably the fastest I answered my own question, doesn't happen often :P